# I designed and made this circuit but it produces only 360V when it should be producing at least +1000V

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, multiplier

The circuit consists of a 9V battery (the input source) connected to a 555 astable multivibrator operating at 1.34 kHz frequency connected to a transformer and a long voltage multiplier chain. According to my calculations, the output should be at least +1000V but it's 360V. What's going on?
[image]

Comment: What’s the transformer specs?

Comment: That's an interesting way of driving a transformer.

Comment: Guesses: The transformer is a 50/60Hz type, not suitable for 1kHz. This isn't a flyback transformer so it needs pure AC on its input — your circuit has a DC offset. The pulse/pause ratio is too high so the transformer saturates anyway.

Comment: What is the voltage at the output of the transformer?

Comment: Transformer: S = 4.5VA, 9V to 230V, 0.5A

Comment: The 555 timer is generating 0V-9V-0V-9V... square wave. The transformer isn't flyback as far as I know. Should I lower the frequency?

Comment: Sounds 50/60 Hz to me. You are most likley burning off a considerable amount of power in the transformer core compared to what a 9V battery can deliver.

Comment: What can I do about the problem?

Comment: @Russell: Can you explain the forward mode / flyback mode a bit more? What difference does it make when there is no feedback from the secondary to the primary?

Comment: I seem to remember you were actually trying to carry out some kind of physics experiment.  I recommended that time around that you buy a powersupply instead of futzing around building one.  If that was too expensive, try [this.](https://www.newark.com/xp-power/a15p-5/dc-dc-converter-1-5kv-660ua/dp/78Y6037)  Your actual task is the physics of particles in an electric field - not building powersupplies.  That link goes to a simple powersupply that will give you 1500 V from 5V, and costs around $120.

Comment: @JRE Thank you, but 120 dollars is too much for a Bulgarian. I prefer to suffer a bit and create my own circuit. If there was something around 10 dollars that does the same function, I can buy. Also, I need it to be somewhat light and not very big in size.

Comment: The one I just linked to is **very** small.  A cube just a couple of centimeters on a side.

Comment: That's great, but it's very expensive. If I had the schematic, I could make one on my own.

Comment: @NovaliumCompany In forward mode Vout ~= Vin x turns ratio. In flyback mode you turn on Q1, charge transformer with "inductive energy" then turn off Q1. Wow!. Q1 collector/transforme connexction "ring" inductively to some higher (sometimes MUCH higher ) voltage. If the transformer is not rated for the flybackvoltage it may break down. If load from multiplier is adequate it will absorb the energy at some higher Vout than 9V. You will get more overall Vout at the risk of getting too much at some points.

Comment: Calculate the power levels and currents you are aiming at here.
Calculate Cap energy (0.5C V^2) and multiply by freq to get power [!!!]. Or look at currents needed to charge caps in time available. And consequent required resistances and losses. It's not rocket science, but it's not wholly non-trivial. Note that at MUCH lower frequencies you get the same notional voltages - but lower power and more chance of V being what is expected. | Driving transformer with a 2 transistor emitter follower pair buffer will give you better drive.

Comment: @NovaliumCompany  IMPORTANT - tell us the POWER level you need at the output. I have looked through your recent questions and its uncertain. In one comment 20 mA at 1500 V is mentioned (3 Watts OUT) but I don't know if that is your actual target. || Why use a 9V battery - almost certainly a very bad idea. | A cheap "electric flyswatter" may do what you want.

Comment: I want the output to be 1.5 mW (0.0015 W) - 1500V and 1 microamp of current.

Answer (score 3):

As this is a standard 50/60Hz transformer, you cannot drive it at 1kHz. Laminated iron cores work up to roughly 100Hz. Above, the eddy current losses are enormous.

As this isn't a flyback transformer, you have to supply AC without a DC offset to it to avoid saturation. You need a H-bridge instead of a single transistor and commutation diode.

As that H-bridge supplies a rectangular voltage to the transformer instead of a sine, you have to use a 1.6 times higher frequency to account for the higher flux. Fortunately, 96Hz is within the limits of a laminated iron core.

Comment: What do you mean AC without DC offset? 4.5/-4.5/4.5/-4.5 instead of 0/9/0/9? What frequency should I drive it at?

Comment: An H-Bridge of four transistors will drive the transformer with +9V and -9V alternatingly. Please look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge. Drive it at 100Hz, that's safe for the flux and won't induce too high eddy currents.

Answer (score 0):

(9V - Q1_Vcesat_V_T1.losses) x 230/9 x 6stages <= 1380
But, probably << 1380.

MAX Vout under forward mode with a multiplier will be less than 1000V if various non-idealities apply.  You need to identify which of these are relevant. The following checklist may help.
Knowing your answers in each case will help us help you.

Addressing/answering the following will help us help you.

- Turn the transistor output circuit right side up so that people' heads do not explode deciphering it.
- What diodes used?
- What is the voltage on the 230V winding?
  ie What is actual V_T1_primary under load?
- What transistor used for Q1?
- What Vcc under load?
- What current drawn?
- What is used to measure Vout (meter basic specs)
- Is there any load?
- What V rating are caps? Multiplier is operating in forward mode (if your dotting is correct) not flyback as some imply - is this intended?
- If you reverse T1 dotting and remove D13 what happens ?
  Note that V_Q1_flyback MAY then be very high.
- ... ?

Comment: Diode is 1N4007; ___ Transistor is Tip112; ___ I use a multimeter; ___ There is no load after the multiplier; ___ Caps are 400V; It's really late and I can't measure/answer your other question sorry